# Laravel 5: Query Builder creates bad SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to create a dynamic query by using checkbox selections of a form and I am using Laravel 5 query builder and here is the the SQL that i get by using `toSql()` method after i got it when the form processed.

```
select `v`.`id ,v`.`model` from `vehicles` as `v`
```

The problem is query causes SQL syntax error since it is missing some quotes. And below is how i create the query

```
$query = 'v.id';

if ($model == 1) {
    $query .= ' ,v.model';
}

if ($marka == 1) {
    $query .= ' ,v.brand_name';
}

$query_result = DB::table('vehicles AS v')->select($query)->toSql();
```

How do i create a proper SQL query? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `addSelect` method or the `selectRaw` method. The `addSelect` method allows you to "chain" select columns to the query. The `selectRaw` method basically just allows you to add a "raw" select expression to the query.

Example with `addSelect`:

```
$query = DB::table('vehicles AS v');

if ($model == 1) {
    $query->addSelect('v.model');
}

if ($marka == 1) {
    $query->addSelect('v.brand_name');
}

$query_result = query->get();
```

Example with `selectRaw`:

```
$query = 'v.id';

if ($model == 1) {
    $query .= ' ,v.model';
}

if ($marka == 1) {
    $query .= ' ,v.brand_name';
}

$query_result = DB::table('vehicles AS v')->selectRaw($query)->get();
```